# Create a string method that takes in a string argument

Tags: string, methods, salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to create a String Method that will take in a String as an argument. 
I am also creating another method that will return the value of that method anytime. I thought this was the correct way to do it.

```
 public String ProvidedDate (String providedDate) {
        String endDate = new String();
        endDate = providedDate;

    }

    public String EndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
```

This is apex on Salesforce btw but it's basically Java. It gives me an error saying "Type cannot be constructed:String". Any ideas where I"m going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's complaining about the

```
String endDate = new String();
```

You don't really need to do that.  Just make it

```
String endDate = providedDate;
```

and you'll be good to go.  In general (in Apex but also in C# and Java) you don't usually need to explicitly construct String objects.